# reusing an object for multiple JSON schemas

Tags: jsonschema

I have two separate JSON schemas (used to validate HTTP request endpoints for a REST API) where they both accept the same exact object, but have different required fields (this is a create vs update request).  Is there a way I can reuse a single definition of this object and only change the required fields?  I know how to use `$ref` for reusing an object as a property of another object, but I cannot figure out how to reuse an entire object as the top-level object in a schema.  My failed attempt so far:

event.json

```
{
  "id": "event",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "start_date": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "end_date": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

event-create.json

```
{
  "id": "event-create",
  "type": "object",
  "$ref": "event",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [ "name", "description" ]
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work.  It seems like it tries to insert the entirety of 'event' into the definition of 'event-create', including the ID and such.  I tried referincing `event#/properties` to no avail.  I can't seem to do a `$ref` as the sole value inside a properties property either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some syntax that seems to work, but I'm not terribly happy with it:

```
{
  "id": "event-create",
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "event" },
    { "required": [ "name", "description" ] }
  ]
}
```

Seems like an abuse of the `allOf` operator, particularly for another case where there are no required fields (thus only one element insid the `allof`).  But it works, so I'm going with it unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: If you want, you could move the `required` clause one level up - but it's all the same really.  This kind of thing is exactly what `allOf` was designed for.

Answer (score 6):

> Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be ignored.
>
> - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3

This is why your example doesn't work.  Anything other than the `$ref` field is supposed to be ignored.

Support for `$ref` is limited to fields whose type is a JSON Schema.  That is why trying to use it for `properties` doesn't work.  `properties` is a plain object whose values are JSON Schemas.

The best way to do this is with `allOf`.  In this case `allOf` can sort-of be thought of as a list of mixin schemas.

```
{
  "id": "event-create",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "event" }],
  "required": ["name", "description"]
}
```